# Two Frameworks use the name for a property

Tags: swift, uiview, namespaces, cocoapods

SwifterSwift has a property name cornerRadius. 
It's an extension to UIView.

While the DropDown framework has a property name cornerRadius. 
DropDown (the class) is a subclass of UIView.

It seems like xCode doesn't know which property I'm referring to. 
I only imported one framework to my file but SwifterSwift's extension still takes effect.

I modified the DropDown framework and everything worked fine but then I reverted because it's not allowed and I wouldn't know how to debug any future problems.

I also tried creating a function in an extension to somehow get around this problem. 
It turns out that I can't directly access DropDown's table (which is the view that we round).

I cant remove the SwifterSwift framework because it has already been used in the project that I'm working on. Although that might be the best option.

Is there a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, namespaces are implicit and belong to target it is defined. So, for your case, the workaround would be to add the target name in the property call.

```
   SwifterSwift.cornerRadius
   DropDown.cornerRadius
```

Let take example of String. It belongs to Swift target and so I can do this

```
   let str = Swift.String("abc".characters)
```

Comment: cornerRadius is an instance property. How would it be called on a DropDown object ? `let dropDown = DropDown()`

Comment: `DropDown` which I have referred is not a `class`, that is your framework. If it is an instance property, you can call by appending the module name. I guess `let dropDown = DropDown.DropDown()` should work.

Comment: I tried that, DropDown doesn't seem to be recognized as a module name.
I'm using cocopods, not sure if thats a problem.

Comment: Yes. I think you will need to provide `module_name` in your Podspec. https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#module_name

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps in [this issue](https://github.com/SwifterSwift/SwifterSwift/issues/176)

Or upvote for adding prefix to all SwifterSwift extensions [here](https://github.com/SwifterSwift/SwifterSwift/issues/180)